# The difference of CI from proc glm and proc means

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, lsmeans

could anyone explain what's the difference when calculate the mean and CI of "class" variable in proc means and proc glm. For example I want to calculate CI for 2 levels Y and N, (Note: not the difference between Y and N) I have 2 codes give me 2 different CI

```
Code 1 :   
Proc means data=KK clm alpha=0.05 ; 
Var UOSMOLVN; 
class lotresp;
Output out=textn n=n mean=mean lclm=lclm uclm=uclm  std=std  ; 
run;

Output: 
Lot  (Yes/No) N    CL for Mean Lower 95%    CL for Mean Upper 95%
N            116   344.1497139              350.8675275 
Y            18    328.3620766              344.0823679 


Code 2 :
proc glm data=KK;
class lotresp;
model UOSMOLVN=lotresp;
means lotresp/clm t ;
quit; 

lotresp  N     Mean    95% Confidence Limits 
N       116   347.509   344.209 350.808 
Y       18    336.222   327.846 344.599
```

Both codes generate the same means, but why CI are different?

Thanks.

H

Answer (score 2):

Because the CIs from proc means are based separately on each sample's SD, whereas the ones from proc glm use the pooled SD as the common SD for all CIs.

Comment: ... hence the homogeneity of variance assumption